# jQuery multiple parent() calls

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this **for loop** that gets the id and text of parents elements:

```
for (var i = 1; i < parents_num; i++) 
{
  var prev_parent_text = jQuery(id).parent().parent().find('> .myclass').text();     
  var prev_parent_id = jQuery(id).parent('ul').parent('li').attr('id');
}
```

What I am trying to do is to increase the number of parent() **by 2** in each loop:
For example,

for i = 1:

```
var prev_parent_text = jQuery(id).parent().parent().find('> .myclass').text();  
var prev_parent_id = jQuery(id).parent('ul').parent('li').attr('id');
```

for i = 2:

```
var prev_parent_text = jQuery(id).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('> .myclass').text();  
var prev_parent_id = jQuery(id).parent('ul').parent('li').parent('ul').parent('li').attr('id');
```

for i = 3:

```
var prev_parent_text = jQuery(id).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().find('> .myclass').text();  
var prev_parent_id = jQuery(id).parent('ul').parent('li').parent('ul').parent('li').parent('ul').parent('li').attr('id');
```

and so on..

I have used the eq() function unsuccesfully:

```
var num = (i*2) - 2
var prev_parent_text = jQuery(id).parent().eq(num).find('> .myclass').text();  
var prev_parent_id = jQuery(id).parent('ul').parent('li').eq(num).attr('id');
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: In your case, use `parents()` instead. But actually, how about making a recursive function so that each time search begins from where it ended?

Comment: You could also write a loop to call `.parent`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep a reference for each, and update the reference for each step:

```
var $id = jQuery(id);
var $li = jQuery(id);

for (var i = 1; i < parents_num; i++) {
  $id = $id.parent().parent();
  $li = $li.parent('ul').parent('li');
  var prev_parent_text = $id.find('> .myclass').text();     
  var prev_parent_id = $li.attr('id');
}
```

Comment: I just were on writing exactly the same code, but you posted before me :-)

Comment: Thanx Guffa! That was exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a custom jquery function for that, like this:

```
$.fn.nparent = function(n) { 
    var elem = $(this);
    for (var i=0;i<n;i++) {
       elem = elem.parent();
    }
    return elem;
}
```

And use it like:

```
var id = $('#element').nparents(4).attr('id');
```